# PostgreSQL: Joining on the characters in a string without UNIONing SUBSTRINGs

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, unpivot

I am new to PSQL.  I am exploring an existing database, which stores `filterbitstring` as a string of 0's and 1's, the first character in the string has an index value of 0, the second, an index value of 1, through the 85th having an index value of (you guessed it) 84.

For the sake of legibility, I am limiting the string here to 15 chars:

`011000001111110`

There's another table, which holds captions for each index value, which I would like to join to.  My challenge is in turning a string of ones and zeros, which could be any length, into a rowset of filterindex,filteractive:

```
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
13  1
14  0
```

I have a working query, which is a testimony to persistence over elegance, and so I am looking for a cleaner, more elegant solution than this monstrousity:

```
SELECT 0 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,1,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 1 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,2,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 2 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,3,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 3 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,4,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 4 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,5,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 5 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,6,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 6 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,7,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 7 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,8,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 8 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,9,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 9 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,10,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 10 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,11,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 11 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,12,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 12 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,13,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 13 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,14,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df UNION
SELECT 14 as "filterindex", cast(substring(df.dsr_filtersbitstring,15,1) as boolean) as "filteractive" FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters as df
```

`filterbitstring`, currently 85 chars long, could grow longer in the future version, and so, I'd like to be able to work with whatever length `filterbitstring` is encountered.

***Is there a better way of rotating the string?***

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Please show sample input and output data

Comment: `with t(x) as (values('011000001111110'::text), ('100010101000101')) select b, n from t, unnest(string_to_array(x, null)) with ordinality as foo(b, n);`

Answer (score 1):

Join to [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html?)

```
select ...
from ...
join generate_series(1, 85)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- A big thank you to Bohemian for the suggestion!
WITH sq AS
  (SELECT generate_series(0, LENGTH(dsr_filtersbitstring)-1),
          dsr_filtersbitstring
   FROM public.assaabloy_core_defaultfilters)
SELECT DISTINCT sq.generate_series AS "filterindex",
                cast(substring(sq.dsr_filtersbitstring, sq.generate_series+1, 1) AS boolean) AS "filteractive"
FROM sq
ORDER BY filterindex
```